# can't get model to properly validate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, models

I have following model. This works but when I don't fill in a rep or a weight I keep getting the error: **undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass**

And this in the **calculate_tonnage** method.

Is there a way so I can check for presence of reps or weight, then calculate_tonnage en *then* check if the tonnage is unique.

I assume that this is the solution but I cannot find how to do this. Does anybody have a  clue what is the best way to solve this problem?

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :contest

  validates_presence_of :user_id, :reps, :weight
  validates_uniqueness_of :tonnage, scope: [:user_id, :contest_id]

  after_validation :calculate_tonnage

  # model helpers
  def calculate_tonnage
    self.tonnage = self.weight * self.reps
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just change your code to:

```
  def calculate_tonnage
    self.tonnage = weight * reps if weight && reps
  end
```

Comment: Can I add an explanation of instance/class data to your answer? I'd write my own but seems unnecessary

Comment: you can also put this logic on the validation declaration:  `validates_uniqueness_of :tonnage, scope: [:user_id, :contest_id], if: "weight && reps"`